# Using Counsel with write-file and insert-file

Tags: ivy, counsel

What is the simplest way to have Counsel versions of `write-file` (`C-x C-w`) and `insert-file` (`C-x i`)?

I would like these replacements to work similarly to `counsel-find-file` (typically bound to `C-x C-f`).  I don't want to add actions (`M-o ...`) to `counsel-find-file` but to have a dedicated functions, as in default Emacs.

Comment: What would Counsel versions of these functions do that Ivy doesn't already provide?

Comment: @Basil: my mistake.  I thought there should be functions equivalent to `counsel-find-file` for `write-file` and `insert-file`, as Counsel was not changing the behavior of these.  But I now created an `init.el` file that just loads Ivy and Counsel and `write-file` and `insert-file` are working as expected (i.e., with Counsel-like behavior).  So, it seems my question is how to make Helm not take over `write-file` and `insert-file` (I cannot just remove Helm, as I need some it's other functions).

Comment: OK.  So, the solution was simply to add `(add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist '(write-file . nil))
  (add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist '(insert-file . nil))` after `(helm-mode)` in my configuration.

Comment: For future reference, Ivy is the package/mode that makes completion Ivy-like (i.e. in the minibuffer, with colours, etc.), and Counsel is the library of handy commands that integrate with Ivy better than built-in Emacs commands do. In other words, Ivy is an alternative to Helm, and Counsel builds on Ivy.